# How to use provide/inject with TypeScript but without vue-class-component

Tags: vue.js, dependency-injection, vue-component

When I use `provide/inject` with class components everything works as expected. But when I use it in a **"normal" vue component** I get **type-errors**.

In this example I get errors when referencing `this.testService`. The code works though.

```
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "HelloWorldBasic" as string,
  inject: ["testService"],

  computed: {
    message(): string | null {
      return this.testService ? this.testService.hello() : null;
    }
  }
});
```

Where did I make my mistake? How should I write the code?

I set up a small project to be able to reproduce it and work with it:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:schnetzi/vue-provide-inject.git
$ npm ci
$ npm start
```

Comment: hello, any news on this one?

Comment: I didn't find any solution for the problem so far :/

Comment: Did you ever solved it @schnetzi? If yes, how?

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit tricky to do, but it is possible using the same workaround that is [commonly used for mixins](https://github.com/ffxsam/vue-typescript-cookbook#how-do-i-properly-annotate-mixins), which entails defining an interface for whatever you want to add to the Vue instance.

In your case, here's how it would be done:

```js
import Vue_ from 'vue';
import MyTestServiceType from 'wherever/it/is';

interface HelloWorldBasicInjected {
  testService: MyTestServiceType
}

const Vue = Vue_ as VueConstructor<Vue_ & HelloWorldBasicInjected>
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "HelloWorldBasic" as string,
  inject: ["testService"],

  computed: {
    message(): string | null {
      return this.testService ? this.testService.hello() : null;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Would there be a way to use this solution with using `export default defineComponent({})` (SFCs)? And without using the composition API?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the `inject` attribute is to use the `inject()` method

```
  import { inject } from 'vue';

  // (...)

  data() {
    return {
      testService: inject('testService') as TestService,
    };
  },
```

After which you can use `this.testService` as you did: `this.testService?.hello()`

`inject()` can even take a default value as second parameter in case the injection isn't resolved.